# (jquery) Keyboard navigation not working

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

Haven't been at this for too long , please excuse any obvious blunders

```
    switch (event.keyCode) {
case 38:
    $("div.sseholdh").removeClass(function(){
    alert($(this).next().attr("title")); // doesn't alert
    $(this).next().addClass('sseholdh');
    return 'sseholdh';
    }); // does remove the class , but doesn't add it to the next sibling
break;
...
default:
    $("div.ssehold:eq(0)").addClass("sseholdh"); // does work
} // switch keycode
```

The html looks like so:

```
<div class="sshold">
  <div title="entry 1" class="ssehold"> entry 1 </div>
  <div title="entry 2" class="ssehold"> entry 2 </div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Does removeClass have a callback? I did not know that.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Since all the way back in 1.4, yep! What _doesn't_ have a "callback" in jQuery these days? :-) (Rhetorical question, I know there is still quite a few functions that don't).

Comment: @GregL , touché, I didn't look at the documentation first. You're right

Answer (score 0):

if I were you I would start of by giving your divs a unique ID aswell.
Maybe its just a personal preference but I feel like it works easier.

next I would throw all your code away(from within the switch) and start with this:

switch (event.keycode){
case 38:
alert('Hello World.');
}

Check if that works. maybe its just your switch thats not working.
I looked it up and keyode 38 is the "L" correct?

(this might not be the best answer given I know but I cant comment yet so this is the only way for now)

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your javascript to the following - there is no need to add the class within the `removeClass()` function:

```
switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 38:
        $("div.sseholdh").removeClass('sseholdh').next().addClass('sseholdh');
        break; //...
    default:
        $("div.ssehold:eq(0)").addClass("sseholdh"); // does work
} // switch keycode
```

**EDIT:** Basic jsFiddle used to test: http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/wy9ZX/

**EDIT 2:** Here is a more complete version that seems to do what you are trying to with the markup on the [actual site](http://www.softpicks.net/test/ssuggest/contact.htm):

```
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            // up arrow
            var highlight = $("div.sseholdh");
            // if nothing highlighted already, highlight the bottom entry
            if (!highlight.length) {
                $('div.ssehold:last').addClass('sseholdh');
            } else {
                // otherwise, change to the previous entry
                highlight.removeClass('sseholdh').prevAll('.ssehold:first').addClass('sseholdh');
            }
            break;
        case 40:
            // down arrow
            var highlight = $("div.sseholdh");
            // if nothing highlighted, select the first entry
            if (!highlight.length) {
                $('div.ssehold:first').addClass('sseholdh');
            } else {
                // otherwise, move the highlight down
                highlight.removeClass('sseholdh').nextAll('.ssehold:first').addClass('sseholdh');
            }
            break;
        default:
            // nothing here, I'm assuming you only want to move the highlight with the arrow keys
        } // switch keycode
```

jsFiddle updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/wy9ZX/2/

Comment: Done that, same result. [link](http://www.softpicks.net/test/ssuggest/contact.htm). The search suggestion thing, top right. Will be back later, have to escort cancer sick grandpa' to hospital.

Comment: Cool, I have updated my answer with some code that should work on that site, as the least I can do for being awesome and looking after your sick grandpa. Hope he conquers the cancer. Let me know how you go.

Comment: It works! You're a life saver. Or, at the very least, a time saver. As a result, I'll stick around and try to help others however I can :) (when not playing WoW :p)